# Maven: accessing resources

Tags: java, maven, resources

One my the mock up testing files i have is loaded by

```
file = new TestData("src/main/resources/sample.json");
```

Unfortunately it is not found, while it is there.

In Maven project, is path i am using correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the project is compiled or packaged, the resources which is stored at the "src/main/resources" will be collected and put to the default package.

You may see further details as the following path/file.

1. target[your_project].jar
2. target\classes\

If you would like to access them, please use only their name, e.g. "sample.json".

I hope this may help to clarify your issue.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: This probably doesn't work without other modifications. If looks like in the original code the file is probably being opened using ordinary file I/O; instead, you'll need to use a Java resource API - for example `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample.json")`